# Interpolation inside of ng-if

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm writing an application with AngularJS on the front-end that dynamically creates form elements using directives, so the name of each form element is not known ahead of time.

I'm currently trying to implement form validation for each element, but that requires interpolation to determine the name of each form element. Here's what I tried to do:

```
<span class="error-msg" data-ng-if="form.dateInput{{ question.questionAnswerId }}.$error.required && submitted">
    Required
</span>
```

However, this gave me the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '{' is an unexpected token at column 15 of the expression [form.dateInput{{ question.questionAnswerId }}.$error.required && submitted] starting at [{{ question.questionAnswerId }}.$error.required && submitted].
```

Since this doesn't seem to be allowed, is there another way I can display a message if a required form element has not been answered?

I was able to interpolate the name of each form element inside of ng-class as follows, so I thought it would work for ng-if as well.

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : form.dateInput{{ question.questionAnswerId }}.$invalid && submitted }"
```

Comment: Try this: `data-ng-if="form['dateInput' + question.questionAnswerId].$error.required && submitted"`.

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok your suggestion worked, thank you! I did see that other question, but it didn't offer up a suggestion how I could avoid using interpolation. I can't believe I didn't think to use the other notation for referencing a JS object property.

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok - This worked well for me; however, I would like to understand what is going on. Is it actually an array or does Angular do something special with [ ]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need interpolation, just access the value directly like:

```
data-ng-if="form.dateInput[question.questionAnswerId].$error.required && submitted"
```